# Serialization of object as json

Tags: java, xml, json, serialization, jaxb

i am serializing java object as json and i want to do something like below but i don't know how to do it.

i have this class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Lookups implements IRsData {

    private List<LookupTO> lookups;

    public List<LookupTO> getLookups() {
        return lookups;
    }

    public void setLookups(List<LookupTO> lookups) {
        this.lookups = lookups;
    }
}
```

generates this output

```
lookups: {
lookups: [2]
0:  {
code: "Hangout"
name: "Hangout"
}
1:  {
code: "Football"
name: "Football"
}
}
```

but i want it like that

```
lookups: [2]
0:  {
code: "Hangout"
name: "Hangout"
}
1:  {
code: "Football"
name: "Football"
}
```

what i have to do to reach to my goal ?